# reading JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON object

```
{"stores":"{
               "1":{
                     "name":"Publix",
                   "address":"1fbdfhbdhsdhsrh",
                   "long":"-84.012502",
                   "lat":"33.878952"},
               "2":{
                     "name":"Publix",
                    "address":"fgsregerge",
                     "long":"-84.125147",
                    "lat":"33.9448"}
          }"
```

}

this is returned in a jquery.ajax call as datatype:json. I am able to access data.stores and that displays all the stores in alert box but data.stores.1 does not work..
How can I read this properly?

Comment: maybe try data.stores[1]

Comment: There are some extra double quotes around the stores.

Comment: yes, you can write `object.attribute` as `object['attribute']`, if there's some "problem" with the attribute name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `data.stores["1"]`, but really you seem to be representing an array in a really odd way.

You should just use an array instead:

```
{
    "stores": [
        {
            "name": "Publix",
            "address": "1fbdfhbdhsdhsrh",
            "long": "-84.012502",
            "lat": "33.878952"
        },
        {
            "name": "Publix",
            "address": "fgsregerge",
            "long": "-84.125147",
            "lat": "33.9448"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, you can access it as such:

`data.stores[0]` and `data.stores[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the unnecessary quotes after "stores":
The JSON should now look like:

```
var dat = {
    "stores": {
        "1": {
            "name": "Publix",
            "address": "1fbdfhbdhsdhsrh",
            "long": "-84.012502",
            "lat": "33.878952"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "Publix",
            "address": "fgsregerge",
            "long": "-84.125147",
            "lat": "33.9448"
        }
    }
};
```

and also try using this code:

```
alert(dat.stores["1"]);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mstjA/

Answer (score 1):

That JSON isn't valid. Might just be a typo from when you brought it into Stack.

```
var data = {
    "stores": {
        "1": {
            "name": "Publix",
            "address": "1fbdfhbdhsdhsrh",
            "long": "-84.012502",
            "lat": "33.878952"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "Publix",
            "address": "fgsregerge",
            "long": "-84.125147",
            "lat": "33.9448"
        }
    }
}
```

You can't use the dot notation to reference a key that is numeric. You'll need to use brackets. These two are equivalent:

```
var a = data.stores["1"].name; /* a = "Publix" */
var b = data["stores"]["1"]["name"]; /* b = "Publix" */
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

There is something weird about this JSON object: it is not valid. You have double quotes around the `stores` value. I guess they should be removed so that the stores property is not a JSON string but a JSON object. Then you could access it like this:

```
alert(data.stores['1'].name);
```

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HHdJR/1/).

If the double quotes are indeed present, well, you have invalid javascript because you are not properly escaping the double quotes inside.

Answer (score 0):

`data.stores['1']` will give you the json object and then you can access the properties within it like

```
var stores = data.stores['1'];
var name = stores.name;
var address = stores.address;
```