# Iterate through JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I have a JSON data like below

```
{
    "computer": [
        {
            "product_id": "6",
        },
        {
            "product_id": "10",
        }
    ],
    "Stationery": [
        {
            "product_id": "11",
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to iterate through these type of JSON data in jQuery/javascript. How can I do that ??

Thanks

Comment: Needs clarification. Where is the data coming from? Is it assigned to a variable or coming from a server?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998013/reading-json-data-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: I think you would want `JSON.stringify`. But wait... jQuery should already done that for you!

Comment: You should search google before asking a question on here :)

Comment: Question is too broad to narrow down what your problem is `retrieve data from JSON dynamically` can be interpreted many ways

Comment: @bcoughlan I got this from jQuery $.post() function which get this data from a codeigniter array.I think the array is multidimensional.

Comment: @Bruno I searched several times in google.

Comment: @PhpPhp Just searched "access json data" and fifth result was [this](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_started_with_json/)

Comment: @charlietfl I am looking for a dynamic way like for loop,foreach loop to retrieve JSON data.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this JSON is stored in a variable myData:

```
var myData=yourJSON
```

So you can read like:

```
myData.computer; // for computer
myData.computer[0].product_id // for 1st product of computer
```

Comment: @Murali  
I tried like below but not get any result.
  
var myData = data;
$('#city').html(myData.computer[0].product_id);

Comment: @Murali   I would like to get universal way/dynamic way like loops to retrieve results from JSON data.

Comment: Use $(data).each(function(obj,index){ }); Check each() method in jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

in javascript `JSON.parse(your_data)`

in php `json_decode(your_data)`

Answer (score -1):

use jquery json parser

```
var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(json_object);
console.log(parsed['computer'][0]['product_id']);
```

Comment: why -1 , this answer is true

Comment: wouldn't it be `console.log(parsed['computer'][0]['product_id']);` though I do agree that the answer to this question is to parse the JSON

Comment: @nasser ghiasi  
I tried like below but not got any result.  
`var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$('#city').html(['computer'][0]['product_id']);`

Comment: @nasser ghiasi  I would like to get universal way/dynamic way like loops to retrieve results from JSON data.