# How to get values of JSON data using loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterate through JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472572/iterate-through-json-data)

I am asking this question again.

I have a JSON data like below

```
{
    "computer": [
        {
            "product_id": "6",
        },
        {
            "product_id": "10",
        }
    ],
    "Stationery": [
        {
            "product_id": "11",
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to iterate through these type of JSON data in jQuery/javascript. How can I do that ??

Thanks

Comment: jQuery has an iterator function - [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on how you want to iterate. As it stands, the question basically is just "How do I iterate in JavaScript?", which is something you can easily look up.

Comment: @pimvdb  I would like to catch "Computer","Stationery" these values.

Answer (score 7):

If `obj` is your object, you can do this :

```
for (var key in obj) {
  console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

I supposed here that you don't have some [JSON](http://json.org/) but a plain javascript object.

If it's really JSON, that is a string, you must parse it first :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can iterate like this

```
var dataObj = {
    "computer": [
        {
            "product_id": "6",
        },
        {
            "product_id": "10",
        }
    ],
    "Stationery": [
        {
            "product_id": "11",
        }
    ]
};

for (var key in dataObj) {
  console.log(key + ' ' + dataObj[key]);
}
```

Comment: console.log is variadic. You can write `console.log(key, jsonObj[key]);` which will let you browse the jsonObj[key]. But please don't name your variable jsonObj : this lets people think that there is such a thing as a "json object".

Comment: yes you are right i'll change the name of it